# Autocomplete textbox with two option to search in c# winform

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, textbox

This is my code on my `FormLoad`-event

```
SqlDataReader dReader;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

if (radioName.checked==true)
{           
    cmd.CommandText = "select RTRIM(Person_name) from MyTable order by Person_name";
}
else
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select RTRIM(Person_number) from MyTable order by Person_number";
}

dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dReader.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dReader.Read())
        namesCollection.Add(dReader[0].ToString());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}

dReader.Close();

tPT.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
tPT.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
tPT.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
conn.Close();
```

I want two options to populate an autocomplete textbox during typing in textbox:

1. By name
2. By number

However it doesn't work. I already tryed this in my `TextChanged`-event, but with no luck. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using optional AutoCompleteSource update all the data into one source. This wont be any problem, since the person wont have to select the options, rather he will type by deciding his option.

```
SqlDataReader dReader;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
cmd.CommandText = "select RTRIM(Person_name) from MyTable order by Person_name";
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
cmd.CommandText = "select RTRIM(Person_number) from MyTable order by Person_number";
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dReader.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dReader.Read())
        namesCollection.Add(dReader[0].ToString());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}

dReader.Close();

tPT.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
tPT.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
tPT.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
conn.Close();
```

or if you want to use the older option,

```
namesCollection.RemoveAll();
SqlDataReader dReader;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(MyClass.GlobalConn());
conn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text; 
namesCollection.RemoveAll();
if (radioName.checked==true)
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select RTRIM(Person_name) from MyTable order by Person_name";
}
else
{
    cmd.CommandText = "select RTRIM(Person_number) from MyTable order by Person_number";
}
dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

if (dReader.HasRows == true)
{
    while (dReader.Read())
        namesCollection.Add(dReader[0].ToString());
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Data not found");
}

dReader.Close();

tPT.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
tPT.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
tPT.AutoCompleteCustomSource = namesCollection;
conn.Close();
```

Notice

> namesCollection.RemoveAll();